# Webservice method that returns objects of struct

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, soap

I have a webservice with two methods 1 that returns a  struct with two arrays:

```
 public struct GetWeatherItemDataStruct
   {
        //public DateTime[] TimeStamp;
        public double[] Value;
        public string[] TimeStamp;
   }

[WebMethod]
public GetWeatherItemDataStruct GetWeatherItemData(string parameterName,string fromTime,string toTime)
{
    GetWeatherItemDataStruct gwiDataStructObj = new GetWeatherItemDataStruct();
    SqlConnection conn  = null;
    SqlDataReader rdr   = null;
    int prameterID      = GetParameterID(parameterName);
    int tblSize         = GetTableSize(parameterName, fromTime, toTime, prameterID);
    double[] result     = new double[tblSize];
    int i = 0;
    string[] tStamp     = new string[tblSize];
    String source       = "Data Source=MASTER-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=WeatherDatabase;Integrated Security=True";
    try
    {
        using (conn = new SqlConnection(source))// create and open a connection object
        {                         
            // 1. create a command object identifying
            // the stored procedure
            SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("GetWeatherItemData", conn);                
            // 2. set the command object so it knows
            // to execute a stored procedure
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            // 3. add parameter to command, which
            // will be passed to the stored procedure
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@WeatherParameterID", "1"));
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@WeatherParameter", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value    = parameterName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FromTimeStamp", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value       = fromTime;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ToTimeStamp", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value         = toTime;
            conn.Open();
            // execute the command
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                result[i]   =   (double)rdr["MeasurementValue"];
                tStamp[i]   =   rdr["Recieved"].ToString();
                i++;                   
            }
            gwiDataStructObj.Value      = result;
            gwiDataStructObj.TimeStamp  = tStamp;
            int b = gwiDataStructObj.Value.Length;
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        //Log exception
        //Display Error message
    }
    return gwiDataStructObj;
}

[WebMethod]
public int[] stringTest(string[] tString)
{

    int numberOfStrings = tString.Length;
    int[] returnS = new int[numberOfStrings];
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfStrings; i++)
    { 
        returnS[i] = 1;

    }
    return returnS;
}
```

On the Client program i can read from the struct tabels as following:

```
  string dtFrom = "2012-10-04 19:05:57:190";
        string dtTo = "2012-10-05 21:50:05:197";
        double[] paramValue;
        string[] timeStamp;
        var client = new WebServiceSample.WebService1SoapClient();
        paramValue = client.GetWeatherItemData(paramName, dtFrom, dtTo).Value.ToArray();
        timeStamp =  client.GetWeatherItemData(paramName, dtFrom, dtTo).TimeStamp.ToArray();
```

This seems to work fine. But i have annother method that returns an array of the same struct:

```
public struct GetWeatherItemDataStruct
{
    //public DateTime[] TimeStamp;
    public double[] Value;
    public string[] TimeStamp;
}


[WebMethod]
public GetWeatherItemDataStruct[] GetSelectedWeatherItemsData(string[] parameterName, string fromTime, string toTime)
{
    int numbeOfParameters   = parameterName.Length;
    GetWeatherItemDataStruct[] getSelectedItemsStructObj = new GetWeatherItemDataStruct[numbeOfParameters];
    SqlConnection conn      = null;
    SqlDataReader rdr       = null;
    int prameterID          = 0;
    int tblSize             = 0;
    double[] result;
    int i                   = 0;
    int counter             = 0;
    for (counter = 0; counter < numbeOfParameters; numbeOfParameters++)
    {
        prameterID          = GetParameterID(parameterName[counter]);
        tblSize             = GetTableSize(parameterName[counter], fromTime, toTime, prameterID);
        result              = new double[tblSize];

        string[] tStamp     = new string[tblSize];
        String source       = "Data Source=MASTER-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=WeatherDatabase;Integrated Security=True";
        try
        {
            using (conn = new SqlConnection(source))// create and open a connection object
            {
                // 1. create a command object identifying
                // the stored procedure
                SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("GetWeatherItemData", conn);
                // 2. set the command object so it knows
                // to execute a stored procedure
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                // 3. add parameter to command, which
                // will be passed to the stored procedure
                //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@WeatherParameterID", "1"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@WeatherParameter", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = parameterName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FromTimeStamp", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fromTime;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ToTimeStamp", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = toTime;
                conn.Open();
                // execute the command
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    result[i] = (double)rdr["MeasurementValue"];
                    tStamp[i] = rdr["Recieved"].ToString();
                    i++;
                }
                getSelectedItemsStructObj[counter].Value        = result;
                getSelectedItemsStructObj[counter].TimeStamp    = tStamp;

            }
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            //Log exception
            //Display Error message
        }

    }        
    return getSelectedItemsStructObj;
}
```

Here im stuck. How do i read the tables for each object?

Comment: Since you're already returning an array, then you wouldn't need the call to `ToArray()` that you have in your first example.  I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, so that's why I have this in a comment.

Comment: "How do i read the tables for each object?" what does this mean?

Comment: Are you just asking how to get the information from a structure inside an array?

Comment: I would recommend removing all of the extra code that doesn't cause the problem. It's too much to look over if it's not relevant. Really, all we need is your struct and the section of code that's failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Based on the comments above.

To get data from a struct inside an array, you retrieve it just like you were setting it.

```
myArrayOfStruct[0].myStructProperty
```

If it's an array IN the struct, it's just:

```
myArrayOfStruct[0].myArrayProperty[0]
```

If you wanted to loop through all structures in the array and all of the items in an array property, you'd next two loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArrayOfStruct.length; i++){
   for (int j = 0; j < myArrayProperty.length; j++){
      myData = myArrayOfStruct[i].myArrayProperty[j]; 
      // do something with the data
   }
}
```

Basically, `myArrayOfStruct[0].myProperty` is the same as accessing it like this:

```
MyStruct myStruct = myArrayOfStruct[0];
myStruct.myProperty
```

Does this answer your question? You set it correctly above. You retrieve it in a similar fashion.